# cx_freeze shortcut doesn't work

Tags: python, cx-freeze

Hello I'm a newbie in python.

I am trying to make an msi file.
It works fine when I run the exe file in the built directory.
But the shortcut that I made on the DesktopFolder won't work.
The reason seems like the shortcut file can't reference UI files.
When I copy & paste the UI files on the DesktopFolder, it does work.
Is there a way to execute shortcut file properly without moving UI files?

Here's my source code.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

company_name = '####'
product_name = 'Robot Parser V1.0'

exebuildOptions = dict(packages=[],
                excludes=[],
                includes=['atexit'],
                include_files=['qwed.ui', 'sub.ui'])

bdist_msi_options = { 'upgrade_code': '{parser-04291986}',
            'add_to_path': False,
            'initial_target_dir': r'[ProgramFilesFolder]\%s\%s' % (company_name, product_name)}



base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
base = 'Win32GUI'



executables = [Executable('__init__.py', base=base, shortcutName="Robot.ini Parser V1.0",
            shortcutDir="DesktopFolder")]

setup(name='Roboparser',
  version='0.1',
  description='Sample cx_Freeze PyQt4 script',
  options={'build_exe' : exebuildOptions, 'bdist_msi': bdist_msi_options},     
  executables=executables
  )
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Is it assuming that the .ui files are in the working directory? If so, have a look at [using data files](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files) in the FAQ.